# Python/Pygame Why aren't my sprites moving?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite

My code is supposed to spawn in either 11, 15, or 19 sprites chosen randomly by the computer, and one of them is moving, and then it stops working. I don't care about seeing the sprites move, as long as they are actually changing x coordinates. They are supposed to just jump to the new position. I am using python 2.7 and pygame. If you see something wrong with my code I'd love to hear it! I'm new to coding in general and I'm hoping to get better. Thanks!
My code is as follows:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))

gray = pygame.Color(220, 220, 220)
black = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)
blue = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)
red = pygame.Color(255, 0 ,0)
white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)


t_delta = 0
t_target = 60*15
t_start = time.time()

g=0

#f = open("results", "a")
#f.write("trial number, answer, reaction time, correct answer, number of balls in left circle at response, number of balls in middle circle at response, number of balls in right circle at response\n")
#f.close()

class tokens(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

token_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

'''t_end = time.time() + 60*15
while time.time() < t_end: (other method for determining 15 minute timer)'''

while t_delta < t_target:

    screen.fill(gray)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, Rect((30,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, Rect((260,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, Rect((490,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.display.update()
    #draws three squares on screen

    if len(token_list) == 0:
        n = random.randint(1,3)
        if n == 1:
            n=11
        elif n == 2:
            n = 15
        elif n == 3:
            n = 19
    #chooses amount of tokens

    x_coords = [265, 305, 345, 385, 425, 265, 305, 345, 385, 425, 265, 305, 345, 385, 425, 265, 305, 345, 385] 
    y_coords = [170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 290, 290, 290, 290]
    # initial x y coords for token 

    left_score = 0
    right_score = 0

    if len(token_list) < n:
        for i in range(0,n):
            token = tokens((255,120,0), 20, 20)
            token.rect.x = x_coords[i-1]
            token.rect.y = y_coords[i-1]

            token_list.add(token)



    if len(token_list) == n:
        token_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        for i in token_list:
            token_direction = random.randint(1,2)
            if token_direction == 1:
                token.rect.x -= 230
                pygame.display.update()
                left_score += 1
                time.sleep(1)

            if token_direction == 2:
                token.rect.x += 230
                pygame.display.update()
                right_score += 1
                time.sleep(1)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            g+=1
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                answer = "left"
                #f = open("results", "a")
                #f.write(str(g) + ", left\n")
                #f.close()
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, Rect((30,140), (200,200)))
                print("You picked left!")
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)
                screen.fill(black)
                token_list.empty()
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)

            elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                answer = "right"
                #f = open("results", "a")
                #f.write(str(g) + ", right\n")
                #f.close()
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, Rect((490,140), (200,200)))
                print("You picked right!")
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)
                screen.fill(black)
                token_list.empty()
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)

        t_delta = time.time() - t_start
```

Comment: you have'nt fixed the same things I pointed out from the last time you posted this.

Comment: I tried to modificate your code but I don't understand rules of game. I got moving tokens but they were moving all around :)

Comment: It's not a game, it's actually for a scientific experiment. Right now, the code is supposed to have a designated number of tokens (the sprites) spawn in the center square, and then every 1 second move to either the right or the left square, in the same slot in a "grid", but in the other square. I plan to have the player guess at any point which square he thinks will have more tokens, and then the tokens move every .2 seconds instead of 1. And if the player is right his score will increase by 1. After 15 minutes of this, the total amount of guesses correct is his score. Does this help?

Comment: if you change `token.rect.x` and call `pygame.display.update()` you don't move token. You have to redraw token. But probably you will have to redraw other elements too (gray background, black rectangle, all tokens)

Comment: With current code and `time.sleep` in loop you have to wait 19 seconds to get pressed key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still a lot work to do but at least tokens are moving.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import random

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Tokens(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# constants (uppercase names)

GRAY  = (220, 220, 220)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

f = open("results", "a")
f.write("trial number, answer, reaction time, correct answer, number of balls in left circle at response, number of balls in middle circle at response, number of balls in right circle at response\n")
f.close()

g = 0

# initial x y coords for token 

x_coords = [265, 305, 345, 385, 425, 265, 305, 345, 385, 425, 265, 305, 345, 385, 425, 265, 305, 345, 385] 
y_coords = [170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 210, 210, 210, 210, 210, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 290, 290, 290, 290]

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# start program

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

state_reset = True

current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
end_time = current_time + 60*15*1000 # ms

# --- mainloop ---

while current_time < end_time:

    if state_reset:
        # chooses amount of tokens

        tokens_to_move = random.choice( (11,15,19) )

        tokens_left = 0
        tokens_right = 0

        # create tokens

        tokens_list = []
        tokens_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

        for i in range(tokens_to_move):
            token = Tokens((255,120,0), x_coords[i], y_coords[i], 20, 20)
            tokens_list.append( token )
            tokens_group.add( token )

        move_speed = 1000

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        time_to_move = current_time + move_speed # ms

        selected_side = None

        state_selected = False
        state_reset = False


    # --- DRAWS ---

    screen.fill(GRAY)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, Rect((30,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, Rect((260,140), (200,200)))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, Rect((490,140), (200,200)))

    if state_selected:
        if selected_side == 'left':
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, Rect((30,140), (200,200)))

        elif selected_side == 'right':
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, Rect((490,140), (200,200)))

    tokens_group.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- CHANGES ---

    if state_selected:
        if selected_time <= current_time:
            state_selected = False

    # moves token

    if tokens_to_move:
        if time_to_move <= current_time:
            time_to_move = current_time + move_speed
            tokens_to_move -= 1
            print 'tokens_to_move:', tokens_to_move
            if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
                tokens_list[tokens_to_move].rect.x -= 230
                tokens_left += 1
            else:
                tokens_list[tokens_to_move].rect.x += 230
                tokens_right += 1
    else:
        state_reset = True

    # --- EVENTS ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            g += 1

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print 'reset'
                state_reset = True

            if not selected_side:
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    answer = "left"
                    f = open("results", "a")
                    f.write(str(g) + ", left\n")
                    f.close()
                    selected_side = 'left'
                    print("You picked left!")
                    selected_time = current_time + 1000 # ms
                    move_speed = 0.1
                    state_selected = True

                elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    answer = "right"
                    f = open("results", "a")
                    f.write(str(g) + ", right\n")
                    f.close()
                    selected_side = 'right'
                    print("You picked right!")
                    selected_time = current_time + 1000 # ms
                    move_speed = 0.1
                    state_selected = True


    # --- CLOCK ---

    clock.tick(20) # 20 FPS 

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    #print 'current_time:', current_time
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FURAS YOU ARE A GOD. One more question: I've added a few things to prints  in the results file, but I'm having trouble getting it to print the "correct side". The problem is that the correct side is determined when tokens_to_move = 0, and the player chooses the side before then and it is printing the stuff in the file before then. Can you help me with this, as well as printing the player score when it is all over? I would also like there to be a 1 second delay in between trials, and it prints("Correct!") or ("Incorrect!") If you could do these final things for me I will love

Comment: you forever and ever. I've uploaded a new question furas is the best. With my new code(or I will in a few minutes because there is a time reset for questions)

Comment: You could add new state - let's call it `state_gameover` - and use it to write result in file and to print result on screen by 1 second. Write to me on email: furas@tlen.pl .